# Conditional column in pandas

Tags: pandas, if-statement

I am trying to create a new conditional column based on column A in the pandas dataframe. column A is a numeric column with values 0 - 50 and has some blanks

I need to create a conditional column with below logic

if column A is >= 50 then output "greater than 50"
if column A is between 20 - 49 then "between 20 to 49"
if column A is between 0 - 19 then "between 0 - 19
else blank

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply func with the given cases will work for you.

```
def cond_func(val):
   if val >= 50:
      return 'greater than 50'
   if 20 <= val <= 49:
      return 'between 20 to 49'
   if 0 <= val <= 19:
      return 'between 0 - 19'
   return None
df['conditional_col'] = df['A'].apply(cond_func)
```

Result df:
[image: Result df]